# Optimizing a Multivariate Nonlinear System

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, control-theory

I am trying to optimize a multivariate system.
The equations of motion are:
$$x^i_{n+1}-x^i_n=\sum_j g^{ij}(|x^l_n-x^m_n|)f^j(|x^l_n-x^m_n|)$$
I want after an arbitrary number of steps $N$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{M-1}(x^i_N)/M\rightarrow max$$
The lower index indicates the time step and upper index the particle index. $g$ is  given tensor depending non-linearly on the relative positions and f is the sought for vector valued function also depending non-linearly on the relative positions. $l,m$ indicate that the vector valued function $f$ depends on all positions $l,m\in [0,M-1]$ can take, where $M$ is the total particle number. I think one could use calculus of variations. But I am not sure how, because in Calculus of variations one usually has an integral and one can use partial integration. But I am not sure how this can be done here.
I hope someone can give me a hint.

Comment: What is your optimization variable?

Comment: i want to optimize with respect to the function f. Isn't this possible with calculus of variations?

Comment: Does the equations of motion involve summation, as in Einstein notation? If so, can you write the summations explicitly?

Comment: @obareey yes einstein summation is used here. I edited it. thanks for the comment

Comment: And what about the indices $l$ and $m$? Where do they come from? Are they also summations?

Comment: @obareey I edited the text. thanks for pointing out the lack of clarity.

Comment: One last question: Are $x^i$ scalars or vectors? You want to maximize the sum of $x_N^i$, which suggests it is a scalar, or are you using some kind of norm in the summation? Also I believe $f^j$ is also a scalar valued function and $g$ is a matrix (2d-tensor?) valued function. Anyway, this scheme looks a lot like multiagent systems and their consensus problem. So, the literature in there might be helpful.

Comment: $x^i$ and $f^j$ are scalars and yes $g$ is a matrix. Yes I have actually already used reinforcement learning to solve this problem. But I wanted to find an analytical way for examples of this type with low dimensionality so that I could compare both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing $f$ has some kind of restriction. Otherwise you can just select $f^j = \infty$. I assume that $\sum_j |f^j| = 1$. Now, note that

$$x_N = x_0 + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} g(x_n) f(x_n)$$

where $x_n^T := [x_n^1 ~ \dots ~ x_n^M]$. You want to maximize the following:

$$ \textbf{1}^T \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} g(x_n) f(x_n) $$

with respect to $f$ where $\textbf{1}^T := [1 ~ \dots ~ 1]$. Note that $\textbf{1}^T g(x_n)$ is the sum of columns of $g$. So, the best function you can use is the one with

$$f(x_n) = [0 \dots 1 \dots 0]^T$$
where the index of $1$ in $f$ is the index of the column of $g(x_n)$ with maximum sum.